# Do Ukrainians need a Transit Visa to Australia for a 2-hour airside transit?

Tags: airports, layovers, australia, ukrainian-citizens

As far as I know you only need a visa if you’re staying for more than 8 hours and want to exit the airport

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, you do need a visa.**

According to the [Department's website](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/lega/lega/form/immi-faqs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia), Ukrainian citizens are not eligible for transit without visa arrangements.

Please see the web page for the [Transit (subclass 771) visa](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/771-) for more information on this visa and how to apply.